# Why were passengers asked to leave infant boarding pass on the seat when leaving then plane?

Tags: tickets, children, aircraft, turkish-airlines

Recently I was flying 2 times with charter airlines.

The "after landing" communication which usually says to stay in your seats and keep your belt fastened had an additional note which I've never heard before: to leave infant boarding pass on your seat or give it to the crew when leaving the plane. What is the purpose of asking that? (I did not obey both times because I had lost it.)

The communication was in English by the Turkish crew to my Polish ears. The airline was Mavi Gök Airlines (MGA); the itinerary was Wroclaw to Antalya and back.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch, please accept the answer if you think it is right, or in case of more answers, the one that helped you most.

Comment: I will but first I will try to ask MGA about that announcement content

Answer (score 26):

My presumption is that you've misheard the announcement.

It's far more likely that you were instructed to leave either the infant seat belt (aka lap belt or seat-belt extender), the infant life-jacket, or some other piece of airline equipment that was distributed to infants before/during the flight.

Not all airlines distribute these items before departure, and even those that do may not do it on all aircraft types or to all (infant) passengers, so it's possible that you were not provided with them even though they were mentioned.

Comment: Broadly, that seems logical…

In detail, how is it likely passengers would be asked to leave the infant seat belts,  infant life-jacket, or other airline equipment that was distributed to infants?

Specifically, which other airline equipment might in your own experience have been distributed to infants?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin That's a very airline-specific question. Some airlines don't use infant seatbelts, and only distribute lifejackets if needed - so will never have this announcement. Other airlines do, and I've certainly heard similar announcements on multiple airlines as a result.  I have no idea what else they might hand out, but can't rule out there being other things which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: Fine and would you mind going back to how that Answer was based on your presumption?